# Guys is it possible to dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu on this machine

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, windows-10

I have Windows 10 installed with UEFI bios, I want to install Ubuntu on it. The first time I did nothing appeared, I just got taken to Windows. The second time I did it the command GNU appeared but I was only able to type and nothing, if I typed exit I would be exited and taken to Windows. So I deleted Ubuntu again and the same problem continued to I formatted my laptop. I just want to know is it possible to download Ubuntu and dual boot it with Windows. If yes, how? My specs are below:
* BIOS: UEFI
* Hard Drive: 1TB
* Operating system: Windows 10
* Laptop Graphics card: NVIDIA Geforce 940M with 2GB Dedicated Ram 
Guys this is important to me, because UBUNTU will help greatly with what I am studying.

Comment: Use Windows to shrink NTFS partitions. Reboot immediately so it can run chkdsk.What brand system? Use nomodeset on booting live installer & first boot or until you install nVidia driver from repository. Boot in UEFI mode. Windows fast start up must be off.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and:http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi and:http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.